# HTTPS displays "site under construction" - Manually remove S and it works yet URL is still HTTPs

Tags: force.com-sites, url

Can anyone confirm that what I am seeing is "expected" or is there a bug...

Scenario:

1. Site configured in a **sandbox** instance requiring HTTPS
2. Code set page reference to `https://sitename`
3. Sites shows under construction page
4. edit the URL to remove the **s**
5. page shows properly but the navigation bar shows the URL as `HTTPS://sitename`

Why would it not work when initially loaded with HTTPS but manually removing the **s** causes the page to display and the URL to change back HTTPS which initially did not display (no other difference in the url)????

**Additional Info**

1. If apex code sets page reference to `http://sitename`
2. Page loads fine and URL shows `HTTP**s**://sitename`

I know that production has the secure.force.com, the part I do not understand why the initial https:// url shows under construction yet editing the url to remove the s shows the page and the url says https again after manually removing the s (no other differences in the url)

I am chalking it up to it is "Just how it is"

Has anyone seen this before, if so is it expected?

Comment: It might be proxy cache issue. Are you behind proxy?

Comment: @EhsanMahmoudi - No, no proxy at all...